# Returning an anonymous class that uses a final primitive. How does it work?

Tags: java, return-value, primitive, anonymous-class

I was wondering if someone could explain how the following code works:

```
public interface Result {
  public int getCount();
  public List<Thing> getThings();
}


class SomeClass {
...
  public Result getThingResult() {
    final List<Thing> things = .. populated from something.

    final int count = 5;

    return new Result {
      @Override
      public int getCount() {
        return count;
      }

      @Override
      public List<Thing> getThings();
        return things;
      }
    }
  }
...
}
```

Where do the primitive int , List reference and List instance get stored in memory? It can't be on the stack.. so where? 
Is there a difference between how references and primitives are handled in this situation?

Thanks a bunch,
  Tim P.

Comment: Would you like to explain which language, OS, and implementation this is for?  Then you can put the info into the tags, or I could.  Right now, you're asking a specific question but not limiting it to people who will know the answer.

Comment: @JRL, that won't explain how it is implemented in Java.

Comment: Sorry, first post on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The used final locals (and any outer `this` references) are copied to synthetic fields of the inner class during construction. References and primitives are, as always, treated the same. Both are (shallow) copied.

You can use `javap` from the JDK to see what is being generated.

Comment: ...which is why they have to be final: so that nobody can tell that the variables are simply copied.

Comment: @Michael It would, of course, be possible to quietly do extra allocations to store mutable state on the heap.

Comment: @Michael: You can hack your way past the finality by using arrays (or any other container; a `Holder` would work well enough). Messy, but works.

Comment: Thanks Tom, Micheal and Donal,  That explains it clearly. I'll take a look at javap when I have time.

Using Apaches Mutable... classes helped me here.